# Image is getting scaled (zoom) when I merge image into word file

Tags: docx4j

I am using below code to merge image in word document .it is not working for image with width 377 and height 650 .here is my code snippet.Please tell me how  to solve this issue  as the image that come in word format is getting zoom with ratio of 123% height and 123% width.

```
                            private void createImage(){
                            List<Object> objects = sourceDocumentEl.getBody().getEGBlockLevelElts();

                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, extension, baos);
                            baos.flush();

                            byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

                            String filenameHint = null;
                            String altText = null;
                            int id1 = 0;
                            int id2 = 1;


                            org.docx4j.wml.P p = newImage(wordML, imageInByte,
                                    filenameHint, altText, id1, id2);
                            objects .add(p);
                        }

                     public static org.docx4j.wml.P newImage( WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage,
                             byte[] bytes,
                             String filenameHint, String altText, 
                             int id1, int id2) throws Exception {

                         BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordMLPackage, bytes);

                         Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline( filenameHint, altText, 
                                 id1, id2);

                         // Now add the inline in w:p/w:r/w:drawing
                         org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory factory = new org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory();
                         org.docx4j.wml.P  p = factory.createP();
                         org.docx4j.wml.R  run = factory.createR();     
                         p.getParagraphContent().add(run);        
                         org.docx4j.wml.Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();      
                         run.getRunContent().add(drawing);      
                         drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);

                         return p;

                     }  

enter code here
```

Comment: why is this tagged as both c# and java? please don't spam unnecessary tags

Comment: Please provide a link to the image in question

Comment: Hi JasonPlutext ,as there is no option to attach image in comment ,i attached in answer ,Please check once

Answer (score 0):

@jason -please check the attach image where u can clearly see the difference on local machine when i run above code and after is ,same code when i try to run on VM machine or Ubuntu Server.[AfterImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8HJT.png)

[Before Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUwsp.png.)

The after image is getting zoomed.